# ArcGIS to Google Maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, mapping

Can ArcGIS mapping be moved to Google Maps?  Looking to migrate from ArcGIS to Google Maps and wondering about the challenges/risks.

Comment: This is an extremely open ended question.  You better clarify what exactly you would want to show on google maps.  It is easy to take shapefiles and things like that, convert them to XML and then you can use them on the google API.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a KML viewer you can use ArcGIS Earth.  It will give you the same look and feel as Google Earth but without knowing exactly what you data you are trying to display or the source and format of the data its hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply display information, Google Maps can work well. Google My Maps can actually directly load shapefiles. Your table will be displayed differently however, so don't expect the same functionality. All of your fields will be condensed into a single column with every field contained in each row. You can export as a KML, which is not convenient to transfer data back and forth since shapefiles and KMLs store data differently.

Google My Maps will geocode for free, so if you have a table it can be imported to create your features. Your fields will remain standard if you do it this way. You cannot export to KML if you geocode.

Google My Maps would work well for displaying simpler maps. You can send a link or embed the map in a webpage. It is free so it has that advantage over ArcGIS Online.

If you plan on completely using Google My Maps, you can set your fields up however you want once you're in there. It is a much simpler program and you lose almost all of your functionality. Just remember that it is not convenient to move large amounts of data back and forth; just geometry.